# UILabel displaying extra fragments of itself, visible after rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont

I have a view controller with a black background, and a white UILabel centered on the screen. Upon rotating the device, fragments of the white text appear in the top corner of the screen.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround? I'm using a fairly large font - AvenirNext-UltraLight at size 120.

Comment: Just to be sure, is there any chance you are creating a 2nd `UILabel` and not just moving the one?

Comment: No. The view controller is otherwise totally empty.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot. Are you drawing manually using `drawRect:`?